# Laravel Relationship Collection iteration returns boolean

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I have a recursive relationship (sections and sub sections)
defined as this in ReportSection model:

```
function sub_sections() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\ReportSection', 'parent_id');
}
```

and I'm trying to iterate through it like so:

```
$section = Section::find($id);
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
          foreach(ReportForm::unlockedForm($section->form_id)->get() as $report) {
            foreach($report->sections()->where('section_id', $section->id)->get() as $reportSections) {
              \Log::info($reportSections);
              foreach($reportSections as $rSection) {
                \Log::info($rSection);
                foreach($rSection->sub_sections as $subSection) {
```

The line `\Log::info($reportSections);` gives `{"id":3,"report_form_id":1,"name_en":"DDD","name_fr":"DDD","created_at":"2016-11-29 07:47:24","updated_at":"2016-11-29 07:47:32","section_id":118,"parent_id":1,"order":99,"hidden":0}`  as expected

but the iterating through it somehow gives a boolean `\Log::info($rSection);` gives `1`

The last line `foreach($rSection->sub_sections as $subSection) {` gives the error `'Trying to get property of non-object'`

Why would iteration through a relationship collection give a boolean? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: changed sub_sections() to sub_sections but the error is still present

Answer (score 0):

You should call the attribute name not the method:

```
foreach($rSection->sub_sections as $subSection)
{}
```

Comment: Yeah i realize this now, and probably would've caught it but the error happens before that matters, I did make the changes and $rSection is still 1.

Comment: It's the same here: `$report->sections->where('section_id', $section->id)->get()`

Comment: I think you have to call it as a method when querying

Answer (score 0):

Ok after taking a break I was able to figure out that the problem was I was iterating through the same collection twice.

Instead of

```
 foreach(ReportForm::unlockedForm($section->form_id)->get() as $report) {
            foreach($report->sections()->where('section_id', $section->id)->get() as $reportSections) {
              foreach($reportSections as $rSection) {
```

It should have been

```
 foreach(ReportForm::unlockedForm($section->form_id)->get() as $report) {
            foreach($report->sections()->where('section_id', $section->id)->get() as $rSection) {
```